# "Unit Test Adapter threw exception:Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information"

Tags: tfs, coded-ui-tests

We are trying to integrate the Coded UI Test automation into TFS 2015. The build definition is created and is working correctly. But Release Definition is having problem.
Below are the tasks added for Release Definition:
1. Windows Machine File Copy
2. Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment
3. Run Functional Tests
Please find the attached screen shots for each task:

[WindowsMachineFileCopy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0hMg.png)

[Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zF5SQ.png)

[Run Functional Tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGnEc.png)

Please find the attachment for the automated test case which is associated in Run Functional Test Task.
[Automated Test Case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OtHF.png)

The Release runs successfully till Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment. Even the Test Agent pop up is opened. After this, the browser is not getting opened i.e., while running Run functional Tests task, it throws below error:
"Unit Test Adapter threw exception: 
Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.."

I have placed all the dll's including the references in bin folder. Please find below screen shot:
[DLL's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nXA9.png)

I am using Visual Studio Premium 2012, Test Agent 2015 Update 3 and TFS 2015.

Installed Test Agent 2013 and now getting attached error in Deploy Test Agent task:
[Test Agent Deploy error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T39BO.png)

Please suggest the solution so that my coded ui starts running through TFS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install **Test Agent for Visual Studio 2013** on the test machine based on the [Compatible versions of TFS,and test agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/lab-management/install-configure-test-agents#compatible-versions-of-tfs-microsoft-test-manager-the-test-controller-and-test-agent)

Also there is a blog introduce the related issue :[Test Agents support for Visual Studio 2015](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gopinath/archive/2015/02/27/test-agents-support-for-visual-studio-2015.aspx)

So, just try to use `Test Agent for VS 2013` instead of `Test Agent 2015 Update 3`, then try it again.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Could you please let me know from where can I download the Test Agent for VS 2013, because all the links i am trying is not having Test Agent for VS 2013, it's having only Test Agent 2015..So could you please send me the link for downloading the test agent for VS 2013.

Comment: @user3129248 You can download agent for Visual Studio 2013 from the older downloads page : https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/, you need to log in with your Visual Studio (MSDN) subscription account.

Comment: @user3129248 You can directly check if this download link works for you: https://download.my.visualstudio.com/sg/en_agents_for_visual_studio_2013_x86_dvd_3009434.iso?t=3ddc9d65-4085-4924-a019-0145996d3f2d&e=1532543219&h=d6f4074870994892f9447ec7dd20dafa&su=1

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link for downloading the agent. I have downloaded and installed the agent. But now when I release, it is giving "'agentlocation' is not a valid path. Ensure that the account with which build agent is running has access to this share." error in Deploy Test Agent Task.

Comment: The test agent is located in "D:\TFS2015\VSTF_TestAgent" path and access is provided for myself, tfsservice. Before I was not getting this type of error when I was using Test Agent 2015. In the same location I have placed the Test Agent 2013. Can you please help me out here

Comment: @user3129248 Just try to grant the correct permission for the **build agent service account** to access the agent location ("`D:\TFS2015\VSTF_TestAgent`" here). Right click the folder  --> Properties --> Security --> ...   or just add the build agent services account to local administrator group, then try it again.

Comment: @user3129248 Besides, The field of "`Test Agent Location`" is optionally, which is used to supply the path to `vstf_testagent.exe` from network or local location. If no path is provided, it will be downloaded from network. You can leave this field blank and let it download from network, maybe you can deploy a test agent successfully.

Comment: Now I have given proper shared path. But now getting different below error: Task 'DeployTestAgent' for machine BLRTRIFWD12721:5985's Error : System.Exception: Look up in registry failed. Test agent failed to install.

Comment: I have attached the screen shot of the Deploy Test Agent task error in the question

Comment: @user3129248 Have you installed the Test Controller? Just following the steps to prepare the environment: [Walkthrough: Using a Test Controller and Test Agents in a Load Test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/ff400223(v=vs.120)). Similar issue here for your reference: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b05a5a31-4728-4cf9-bc92-f4dea8eff18b/failed-to-register-this-test-agent-with-the-test-controller?forum=vsunittest

Comment: I have provided the below path for Test Agent: \\BLRTRIFWD12721\TFS2015\VSTF_TestAgent\vstf_testagent.exe If I give D:\TFS2015\VSTF_TestAgent, it is giving the same error message that is it not able to access the path. Tried without giving path, but it is giving error. So I gave the above path. But now it is giving other error as I have uploaded in the question : "Test Agent Deploy error"

Comment: I have already installed the Test Controller and configured it.

Comment: @user3129248 Just check if you match the [Demands and prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/test/visual-studio-test-agent-deployment?view=vsts#demands-and-prerequisites) to deploy the test Agent. Besides, you can try to [install the Test Agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh546459.aspx#agent) manually on the target machine (`BLRTRIFWD12721` here), then try it again.

Comment: Yes, I have already installed the Test Agent in BLRTRIFWD12721 and the Test Agent status is "Online". It shows the status.

Comment: @user3129248 Have you resolve the issue? any update?

Comment: No, we are getting the same issue. The Deploy Test Agent task is getting failed. So we installed Test Agent 2015 again. Because, for example, if we do not give the path of Test Agent, then it will automatically install Test Agent 2015. So installed it and given the path. But getting Unit Test adapter failed issue

Comment: Is it something related to Data Source (Excel file)?